# Vielen Dank (dafür), dass…

Tags: word-usage

1. *Vielen Dank dafür, dass Sie heute Zeit für mich hatten.*
2. *Vielen Dank, dass Sie heute Zeit für mich hatten.*

Which is correct? Google finds 300k hits for "Vielen Dank dafür, dass" and 20.9m hits for "Vielen Dank, dass"

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine. The verb *danken* usually goes with a prepositional object *für*+accusative, and so does the phrase *Vielen Dank.*

> Vielen Dank für ihre Zeit.

> Vielen Dank (dafür), dass Sie heute Zeit für mich hatten.

So the dependent clause explains the prepositional object *dafür*. But it sounds a bit overblown that way so most people drop the *dafür*.

This is true for many instances of *da*-Adverbs but not for the majority. So you have to learn it by phrase if dropping the *da*-Adverb sounds natural and when it doesn't. Sorry for that.

Comment: I gather that if you want follow grammar strictly then you'd use "dafür", but since it's not really needed to convey meaning it can be easily dropped.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no rule of thumb for that. Some very common expressions as *darauf warten, dass …* really need their da-Adverb but for others as *sich (darauf) freuen, dass …* it's optional.